# Multiplying matrix with another one in C++

Tags: c++, math, multidimensional-array, multiplication

I have problem with my assignment, where I have three matrixes. I should multiply first one(a) by second(b) and the result return in third one(c). What is also worth to say is i can only move by pointers, I can't use index in loops.

The main problem is in case where dim1 == dim and matrix is not square one. All should be written in C++. My code returns almost good result but it looks like in the first row I pass garbage values. It looks like I don't fill these with values. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

```
void multiply(int* a[], int* b[], int* c[], int dim1, int dim2, int
        dim3){

    for(int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dim3; j++){
            for( int k = 0; k < dim2; k++){
                *(*(c+i)+j) += *(*(a+i)+k) * *(*(b+k)+j);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dim3; j++){
            cout << *(*(c+i)+j) << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main(){ 
    const int dim1 = 3;
    const int dim2 = 2;
    const int dim3 = 3;


    int a[dim1][dim2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    int b[dim2][dim3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int c[dim1][dim3] = {};

    int *tab1 [dim1];
    int *tab2 [dim2];
    int *tab3 [dim3];


    for(int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
        *(tab1+i) = *(a+i);
        *(tab2+i) = *(b+i);
        *(tab3+i) = *(c+i); 
    }

    multiply(tab1,tab2,tab3,dim1,dim2,dim3);
}
```

Comment: You should set `*(*(c+i)+j) =0` before the `k` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct except `tab` initialization. You iterator to `dim1=3`, but `tab2` is `dim2=2` size. Try this:

```
const int dim1 = 3;
const int dim2 = 2;
const int dim3 = 3;

void multiply(int a[dim1][dim2], int b[dim2][dim3], int c[dim1][dim3], int dim1, int dim2, int
        dim3){

    for(int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dim3; j++){
            for( int k = 0; k < dim2; k++){
                *(*(c+i)+j) += *(*(a+i)+k) * *(*(b+k)+j);
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < dim1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dim3; j++){
            cout << *(*(c+i)+j) << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[dim1][dim2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    int b[dim2][dim3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    int c[dim1][dim3] = {};

    multiply(a,b,c,dim1,dim2,dim3);
}
```